# How can I locate an NPC in Wizardry 8?

Tags: wizardry-8

I had RFS-81 in my party, but he has disappeared.

I last saw him before entering the Rapax castle, but can't remember where,and I was doing a lot of travelling just before entering the castle.

[This page](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/374906-wizardry-8/faqs/15482) says

> Returning Location: Wherever you Dismissed him
>   Will    Not Go: None (Rapax Away Camp)

I am in the Rapax Castle, not the away camp.

I cannot remember where I dismissed him and it would be excruciatingly tedious to search everywhere.

So, is there any way, maybe a game editor, that I can locate this NPC, without exploring the entire map?

Comment: If I remember correctly, RFS-81 returns to Arnika when dismissed. Try looking for him near the Dark Savant's tower.

Comment: Hmm, on the one hand, that's not where I recruited him; on the other hand, he does look like those savant guards, and on the third hand, I have recently teleported into the savant tower & back out again, although I think that he was gone by then. Plus one for taking the time to comment; great to know someone else is still playing. I will check it out & if you are correct, will invite you to post and answer, which I will accept.

Comment: Wah! It looks like that quote above was true - "will not go ... Rapax away camp". I found him hanging out just outside (was beginning to think that he had died in combat & I had not noticed). Thanks for encouraging me to explore

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica could you add this as an answer? I have also found myself in this situation, and this post helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by @meskobalazs, turning a comment into an answer:

> RFS-81  will not go ... Rapax away camp.

I found him hanging out just outside (was beginning to think that he had died in combat & I had not noticed)